# counting values in python

Tags: python

How to count the number of occurrence of a values in a  dictionary in python

```
a = dict()
a['cat'] =      1
a['fish'] =     1
a['dog'] =      2  
a['bat'] =      3
a['aardvark'] = 3
a['lion'] =    4  
a['wallaby'] =  5
a['badger'] =   5
```

output Expected:

```
KEY  Count
 1   2
 2   1
 3   2
 4   1
 5   2
```

`EDIT`

Sorry , i meant to say counting values

Comment: In a dictionaty, each key can occur at most once.  The number of occurences can be determined by `int(key in a)`, which returns `0` or `1`.

Comment: keys can only occur once...do you mean values?

Comment: a dict is made up of only unique keys, so number of  occurrence of a key is 1.

Comment: So what should the result look like? `len(a)` ?

Comment: What do you mean with number of occurence? (from a non-answer by Giorgos Komnino).

Comment: Do you want to count the number of *all* values?  Of just a single value?

Comment: By definition, a dictionary contains a given key at most once. Can you give more details about what you mean, and what results you want?

Comment: @Rajeev it's still not clear what you want as the output.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want as an output. For your example, what should the output be?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: Please look at the edit.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want to use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects); it let's you handle most counting use cases with ease.

```
from collections import Counter
a = dict()
a['cat'] =      1
a['fish'] =     1
a['dog'] =      2  
a['bat'] =      3
a['aardvark'] = 3
a['lion'] =    4  
a['wallaby'] =  5
a['badger'] =   5

print Counter(a.values())
```

Output: `Counter({1: 2, 3: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1, 4: 1})`

Or, to format it a little for you:

```
for key, value in Counter(a.values()).most_common():
    print key, value
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 2
5 2
2 1
4 1
```

Or, to match your output *exactly*:

```
for key, value in sorted(Counter(a.values()).items()):
    print key, value
```

Here we sorted on the key (numbers 1 through 5).

Comment: That's not counting the number of occurrences of values in a dictionary, ist it?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: No, but I think the OP doesn't know what he's asking.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of question is more about psychic skills than technical. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(a.values())
Counter({1: 2, 3: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1, 4: 1})
```

Comment: Hey Thanks..I should have been cleared when i stated the question initially..Had a long day at work :)

Answer (score 1):

a collections.Counter is the best tool for this job (see answer by Martijn Pieters) -- however, it was introduced in python 2.7.  If you need a 2.5+ solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(int)
for v in a.values():
    d[v]+=1
```

Comment: @JonClements -- Because I didn't think of it.  (I don't generally use the fact that `int()` returns `0`).  I'll update.  (Thanks)

Comment: Or use [this backport of the Counter class](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Or use setdefault etc... etc... - but think this one's been answered happily, but may have used our crystal balls out :)

Comment: @JonClements: I'll see if I can polish up a spare one for future questions; my current one is surely cracked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of the values do:

```
sum(a.values())
```

If you want the frequency of the number of occurrences do:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(a.values()).items()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a horrible feeling, and while it's unclear, that `len(a)` might be an answer...

However, it's also possible that:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(a.values())
```

is also likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily without importing anything:

```
results={}
for v in a.values():
   results[v]=results.get(v, 0) + 1

for k,v in results.items():
    print k,v
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 1
3 2
4 1
5 2
```